# When joining tables, style of vector layer can't find new column in QGIS

Tags: qgis, style, attribute-joins, choropleth

When I joined a csv file with the attribute table of my vector label everything's cool. Now, when I open the attribute table of the vector layer I can see that I successfully added the new designated column say: `data`

But when I want to add a graduated style to that new `data` column in my vector layer I can't find it in the column drop down menu.

I don't understand, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which kind of data type is `data` column?

Comment: Just found out that it's a string type, so yeah now it seems obvious that it doesn't recognise the column there. But when I create a `csvt` file with the same name and try to convert that column to "Integer", I get only zero's. The data ranges from `-1.13 to 0.22`.

Comment: Integer will not work in your kind of data. You need to use real/float/double. @HDunn answered how to convert the field to real. Try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Graduated symbols can by applied to numeric (integers/real/float/double) fields only. 
Open the properties of the layer and take a look at the field tab. If `data` is listed as string, you convert it to a decimal by calculating a new field with

```
to_real("data")
```

Define the field as Decimal number and make sure it's long enough, and the precision is 2 (at least) to fit your decimal values.

Comment: Thanks! Converting the type of variable like this seems better than creating those 'magic' csvt's.

Comment: It still doesn't work. When I convert the numbers in a new column every value returns a zero...